# Cant click download link in Gmail

Tags: c#, html, .net-core, gmail

My service creates an email that gets sent to a user. In the email, there's a link to my service, that downloads the file.

- When I click the link in Gmail, the service gets called, but the downloaded/yielded file does not start download.
- When I right click->copy url->paste into a new tab, it downloads.
- When I forward the email to an Outlook client, it works when I click the link.

The body of the email looks like this :

```
 Click to <a href=http://localhost:1234/download?token=mytoken target="_blank">download</a>
```

With quotes :

```
Click to <a href="http://localhost:1234/download?token=mytoken" target="_blank">register</a>
```

My controller on the endpoint looks like this :

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Get(string token)
{
    ...
    var result = new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("mypath"), "application/exe")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "myFile.msi"
    };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: try adding some quotation marks around your link, so your HTML is valid (as a hint: validate the link that's actually being _opened_ when you click. i'm betting that the token is missing ;))

Comment: I actually removed that just now, let me re-introduce that and paste the code as well

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, see edits please. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Silvestre, I have an answer as to why it doesnt work, but not a fix. If I recall correctly, google reroutes the request, and the content gets lost in the void. You can get it to work by either using, or not using, https (try both, i dont recall).

Comment: @WynDiesel yep, it was because gmail is in a https address and the link wasn't, tried that yesterday. Thanks!